# A small but nagging bug in VSCode LaTeX Workshop keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, vscode

I am using VSCode with LaTeX Workshop extension for writing LaTeX. I am a fan of its helpful shortcuts for math symbols. But recently, the shortcuts began exhibiting a nagging bug that isn't critical to workflow, but is very inconvenient.

So, for example, when I type "@a" and press enter, I get "\alpha". But, if I first type (say) "@(" (which gives me "\left( \right)" and then type "@a" and press enter, the program does not convert it to "\alpha"; instead the enter key puts me to the next line. So after typing "@(", I need to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> first and then type "@a" to get my "\alpha".

Example:

```
typing "@(, Enter, @a, Enter" gives\
"\left( @a \
 \right)"

typing "@(, Enter, esc, @a, Enter" correctly gives\
\left( \alpha \right)
```

This did not use to be the case. But it recently started occurring with any shortcut that places me inside a bracket (such as \( -> \( \), @/ -> \frac{}{}, @2 -> \sqrt{}, @I -> \int_{}^{}, etc.); any subsequent shortcut without pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> is ignored as above. Since there are so many such shortcuts that I use on a daily basis, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> requirement is becoming a small but quite incessant distraction.

Does anyone know how to fix the setting to get rid of this problem?

Thanks,

HR

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This sounds like something which might be better suited in the issues or discussions of the plugin itself, which seems to be available at https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the site!

Comment: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3764